# SignalR Self-Host only localhost javascript clients works

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

I have a SignalR self-hosted application with javascript (jquery) clients. It works well locally, but I haven't found a way to connect from a remote computer. 
I always get a Bad Request - Invalid Hostname / HTTP Error 400

I am running Visual as administrator, I have disabled the firewall, as you can see in the following code, I have set the server side url as `url = "http://+:8081/";` and I have set my IP address in jquery connection and the reference to the auto-generated signalR hub script.

```js
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://192.168.2.101:8081/signalr";
    var con = $.connection.myHub;

    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    var Nrobot = 1;
    con.client.broadcastMessage = function (Nrobot, message) {
    };

    $.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
  $('#btn_P06P07').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "LT");});
  $('#btn_P01P02').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "LTI");});
  $('#btn_P03P04').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "T")  ;});
  $('#btn_P05P06').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "TI") ;});
  $('#btn_P00P03').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "RT") ;});
  $('#btn_P02P05').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "RTI");});
  //MiddleRow
  $('#btn_P04P07').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "L");});
  $('#btn_P12P15').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "LI");});
  $('#btn_P10P13').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "C");});
  $('#btn_P06P11').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "R");});
  $('#btn_P13P14').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "RI");});
  //BottomRow
  $('#btn_P11P12').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "LB");});
  $('#btn_P07P10').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "LBI");});
  $('#btn_P00P01').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "B");});
  $('#btn_P02P03').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "BI");});
  $('#btn_P04P05').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "RB");});
  $('#btn_P14P15').mouseover(function () {con.server.send(Nrobot, "RBI");});
        $('#btn_oClaw').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "OClaw"); });
        $('#btn_cClaw').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "CClaw"); });
        $('#btn_rBoom').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "RBoom"); });
        $('#btn_lBoom').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "LBoom"); });
        $('#btn_lPancam').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "LPancam"); });
        $('#btn_rPancam').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "RPancam"); });
        $('#btn_rElbow').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "RElbow"); });
        $('#btn_lElbow').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "LElbow"); });
        $('#btn_lFuture').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "LFuture"); });
        $('#btn_rFuture').mousedown(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "RFuture"); });
        $('#btn_oClaw').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_cClaw').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_rBoom').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_lBoom').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_lPancam').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_rPancam').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_rElbow').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_lElbow').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_lFuture').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $('#btn_rFuture').mouseup(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });  
        $('#Joystick').mouseleave(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });
        $(window).mouseleave(function () { con.server.send(Nrobot, "C"); });  
    });
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="robotCSS.css" />
</head>
<body>
                <table id=Joystick>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="LTledClass" name="P06P07" id="btn_P06P07" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="LTledClass" name="P01P02" id="btn_P01P02" style="height:25px;width:25px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="TledClass" name="P03P04" id="btn_P03P04" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="TledClass" name="P05P06" id="btn_P05P06" style="height:25px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="RTledClass" name="P00P03" id="btn_P00P03" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="RTledClass" name="P02P05" id="btn_P02P05" style="height:25px;width:25px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="LledClass" name="P04P07" id="btn_P04P07" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="LledClass" name="P12P15" id="btn_P12P15" style="height:50px;width:25px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="ledClass" name="P10P13" id="btn_P10P13" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="RledClass" name="P06P11" id="btn_P06P11" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="RledClass" name="P13P14" id="btn_P13P14" style="height:50px;width:25px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="LBledClass" name="P11P12" id="btn_P11P12" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="LBledClass" name="P07P10" id="btn_P07P10" style="height:25px;width:25px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BledClass" name="P00P01" id="btn_P00P01" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="BledClass" name="P02P03" id="btn_P02P03" style="height:25px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="RBledClass" name="P04P05" id="btn_P04P05" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
                            <input type="button" class="RBledClass" name="P14P15" id="btn_P14P15" style="height:25px;width:25px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="RightPanel" width="100" height="150" bgcolor="red" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="t">Claw</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="t">Boom</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Open" name="OClaw" id="btn_oClaw" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Raise" name="RBoom" id="btn_rBoom" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Close" name="CClaw" id="btn_cClaw" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Lower" name="LBoom" id="btn_lBoom" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p class="t">PanCam</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Left" name="LPancam" id="btn_lPancam" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Right" name="RPancam" id="btn_rPancam" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p class="t">Elbow</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="t">Future</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Raise" name="RElbow" id="btn_rElbow" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Left" name="LFuture" id="btn_lFuture" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Lower" name="LElbow" id="btn_lElbow" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="BTN" value="Right" name="RFuture" id="btn_rFuture" style="height:20px;width:50px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

    <ul id="Tmess"></ul>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="http://192.168.2.101:8081/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Centauri.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
        // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
        // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
        // for more information.
        string url = "http://+:8081/";
        using (WebApp.Start(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {                       
                    EnableJSONP = true                      
                };                    
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });

        //app.MapSignalR();
        //app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration() {EnableJSONP=true});

    }
}
```

Nothing worked.

Thanks a lot,

Best Regards,

Comment: I guess that the problem is `string url = "http://+:8081/"; using(WebApp.Start(url))`. I think it still listens only `localhost`.

Comment: Hi MaKCbimKo, Thanks for your fast answer, how can I change that then?

Comment: Have you tried to use "http://*:8081/" instead of "http://+:8081/" ?

Comment: Yes i did, same all.

Comment: What if you will try to specify exactly your IP address in here? like `http://192.168.2.101:8081`

Comment: I just checked, still the same HTTP 400 Bas Request answer

Comment: Actually, I think you are right it still binds to localhost when I check on the IIS icon of the task bar and go to ViewSites/JavascriptClient is says http://localhost:31072/ even if the url is set to "http://*:8081" or anything else for that matter, maybe it is is the applicationhost.config that I need to change something...I am going to check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the solution.

I needed to edit the applicationhost.config file, for some reason the change in the url string did not take effect.

```
            <site name="JavascriptClient" id="7">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\oloyau\OneDrive\Freelance\1 - Completed\NI USB6501\CentauriBotServer\BotSeverSignalR\C#\JavascriptClient" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:31072:**localhost**" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

By changing the localhost part in the binding protocol parameter to

> *:31072:*

It's italic but it is actually surrounded by * , I don't know how to show them instead of italic formatting, sorry.

Now it works from other computers on my network.

Hope this could help the next one in trouble...

Thanks